# zet version via CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to set the "Title" attribute in css style if the class is "Zet"

```
#item-:before { content: "\f031"; }

.zet-version { attr(title): " Zet"; }
.zet-version {
    color:red !important;
}
```

But all I get is - nothing.

Any one?

Comment: You can also use jQuery to set `title` attribute based on CSS class-selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

CSS is for styling.

You'll need to use HTML:

```
<div class="zet-version" title=" Zet">...
```